# How to create a custom recover in Beego?

Tags: go, beego

How to override Beego's recoverPanic? I have set the flag `recoverpanic = false` and write my own recover but have no luck, it just print the panic message to the console instead jumping to my recover function.

```
func main() {
    defer recoverPanic()
    beego.Run()
}

func recoverPanic() {
    if err := recover(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Panic should go there")
    }
}
```

I want to catch all unexpect errors, e.g `nil pointer`, write some log and send email to our maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `recoverPanic` at the beginning of every goroutine. You add the `recover` in the `main` function and it won't cache the `panic` of request.

Try this in Beego:

```
func (c *MainController) Get() {
    defer recoverPanic()

    ... Your Code ...
}
```